# why getClass() from superclass variable returns subclass class name?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Im confused, when i use getClass( ) from a superclass reference variable that's pointing to a subclass object, the result is the subclass.
Heres a simple example:

```
public `class` TestGetClass
{
    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Object obj = new Integer(20);
        
            System.out.println("obj class: " + obj.getClass());
        }
}
```

The output gives me the Integer class instead of the Object class.

`obj class: class java.lang.Integer`

Can someone explain please

Comment: This behaviour is called [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch).

Comment: Thanks @Turing85, it seems that runtime objects are the ones being called from a reference variable

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is simply:

`Object.class`.

---

`obj.getClass()` in java could plausibly be interpreted in two different ways:

1. It means: Take the expression 'obj', which is a reference (i.e., a pointer). Follow the pointer and find the object it is pointing at. Ask **that object** what its type is.
2. just like 1, except, because the variable type was `Object`, invoke the implementation of the `getClass()` method from the `java.lang.Object` class. i.e., no dynamic dispatch.
3. It means: Take the locally declared variable named `obj`. What type did I declare it as, right here in this method? Don't care about the object/pointer at all, just the declaration.

Now, the java lang spec is crystal clear: In java, #1 is what happens. #2 is not available (you can't opt out of dynamic dispatch. As a matter of obvious language design, private methods don't do it because they don't need it, and static methods don't do it because, by being static, they just aren't a part of the hierarchy in the first place - so those seeming exceptions really don't apply. There is no other way to opt out).

Here's the thing about option #2 though: **is completely pointless**.

In java, you can't have mystery meat variables. Somebody declares them, and the type is written right there in the source file. There is no such thing as 'eh, figure it all out at runtime'. Even java10's `var` doesn't work that way (it's still locked in, for sure, at compile time).

So, you **already know**. It is object, what point is there to repeat it?

If you want a `java.lang.Class<?>` instance that represents `Object`, there's syntax for this. it is:

`Class<?> objClass = Object.class;`